# uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when using JSON object with name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, mongodb

I'm using D3js with Mongodb and AnguarlJS to display my data. All is good that it works until when I give my JSON array a name. Then angular starts complaining about stuff and I'm not sure why.

this is the original json array that works with this original code

```
[

  {
    "defaultCategory":"Happy",
    "timesUsed":2704659
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Sad",
    "timesUsed":4499890
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Laughter",
    "timesUsed":2159981
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Smirk",
    "timesUsed":3853788
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Flirty",
    "timesUsed":14106543
  }
]


d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
           d.timesUsed =+ d.timesUsed;
    });
```

but when i change the json to this format, it breaks

```
{
  "mymood":[

  {
    "defaultCategory":"Happy",
    "timesUsed":2704659
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Sad",
    "timesUsed":4499890
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Laughter",
    "timesUsed":2159981
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Smirk",
    "timesUsed":3853788
  },
  {
    "defaultCategory":"Flirty",
    "timesUsed":14106543
  }
]

}


 d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
        data.mymood.forEach(function(d) {
           d.timesUsed =+ d.timesUsed;
    });
```

In the chrome console the error is happening at the line data.mymood.foreach line,
but i dont understand why because its exactly returning the same json as if there was no name like this

[object, object, object,object,object]

and the parameter d in the function also returns the same object within the array

*edit*

Error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

console.log(data) -> Object {mymood: Array[5]}

console.log(data.mymood) -> [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

gist for those who are interested in the full code

https://gist.github.com/gwong89/e3a29b64d94ad20256bb

Comment: When you `console.log(data)` or `console.log(data.mymood)` what comes out?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: check edit above, i just added

Comment: What happens when you do typeof data.mymood? Perhaps the nested stuff is still a string, although your edit suggests it's correctly formatted

Comment: This isn't causing that problem but you *probably* want `+=` instead of `=+`

Comment: @Pointy I think both should work.

Comment: @OscarJara both are syntactically correct, but one will add the right hand side to the left hand side, and one won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Oscar had pointed out, the forEach loop works fine. However, after look closely at your gist, if you try to use the mymood key, make sure you also change line 55 where you were using

```
var g = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(pie(data))
```

to

```
var g = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(pie(data.mymood))
```

Also on line 76 where you had

```
var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {
```

to

```
var total = d3.sum(data.mymood.map(function(d) {
```

I grabbed your project repo and tried these out on my local environment, and I can render the pie chart and popup without seeing any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize the errors were from there, chrome console kept complaining it was the actual d3.js file

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine *(from what I've tested)*. I will suggest to try *debugging* your code or if you feel more comfortable try doing many `console.log(...)` as possible and keep checking your *browser console* from the beginning *(I have nothing else to say)*. Try to also use *Developer Tools* from *Chrome* which is a better option.

I've tried to replicate your context by using *`d3.js`* library and uploaded a *`json`* file with your *data* to my *Dropbox* just to be able to perform an *ajax* request and everything is fine again *(also new `JSON` structure is valid)*. Here's what I did, probably could help you to learn something new *(see below)*.

**Possible hints/suggestions to fix your issue:**

> According to the question title, it seems that `data.mymood` is `undefined` so you are not able to do a `forEach` of something that doesn't exist. Try validating things and avoid null pointers *(see example)*.
>
> *`JSON`* structures are valid so that's not the problem.
>
> Syntax seems to be valid from what I've tested.
>
> Check if there's a conflict between libraries, try to do some research about using all the libraries needed together *(not sure if this is your situation but could happen)*.
>
> Check your *browser console* and do some *debugging* as the first paragraph says.
>
> Check if your request is not timing out or something else is happening, check the *Network* tab or log your requests in *browser console* using *Developer Tools* from *Chrome* *(just saying)*.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/29f6n8L7/

```
d3.json('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/data.json', function(data) {
    
    // Some ways to avoid null pointers
    var obj = (data || {}), // If 'data' is null, initialize as an Object
        moods = (obj.mymood || []),  // If 'obj.mymood' is null, initialize as an Array
        time = 0, 
        mood;
        
    // Same way to get 'mymood' from the object
    console.log('Your obj.mymood contains: %o', obj.mymood);
    console.log('Your obj["mymood"] contains: %o', obj['mymood']);

    /**
     * I will suggest to use a traditional loop instead of 'forEach'.
     * Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/1178686
     * for a better explanation    
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < moods.length; ++i) {
        mood = moods[i];
        if (mood) {
            time += mood.timesUsed;
        }
    }
    
    // Output
    console.log('Sum of timesUsed is: %s', time);
});
```

Comment: hey oscar, great post and i appreciate it. I fiddled around with your suggestion, the for loop works but it will take a great deal of pain to rename all my variables and hack something to work. Also, i checked the chrome console again and realized was coming from the d3.js library itself.

Answer (score -3):

Arrays have a built in for each in es5, objects do not.

Comment: data.mymood returns an array, not an object.